# Rails 4 shallow routes menu parameters undefined error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have shallow routes like below:

```
    resources :venues, shallow: true do
        #Halls
        get "hall/:id/exhibition" => "halls#exhibition", as: :exhibition
        get "hall/:id/visit" => "halls#visit", as: :hall_visit
        get "structure", :to => "venues#venue_structure"
        resources :asset_types, :booths_tags, :tags, :uploaded_files, :events, :chats
        resources :halls do
            resources :webcasts
            resources :booths do
                resources :chats
            end
        end
    end
```

Problem with this is with below helper where I need to provide `@booth` resource as a parameter:

```
hall_booths_path(@booth.hall)
```

But this is not always possible especially when it gets to `index` action as it does not set `@booth` resource.

Is there a good approach to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you're in `booths#index` action, you have your `hall` id, so you could set `@hall` instance variable:

```
@hall = Hall.find(params[:hall_id])
```

and then, you just can do following:

```
hall_booths_path(@hall)
```

Comment: Would you put this under index action? I just tried this just after `@booths = Booth.all` but it cannot find the `@hall` variable. I've got the helper inside `sidebar_menu` function which is called by `after_action :sidebar_menu` I thought `@hall = Hall.find(params[:hall_id])` is set inside `index` action it would set `@hall` first so I can use this inside the helper but I'm getting `nil` somehow

Comment: @PassionateDeveloper I guess you should set `@hall` in `before_filter`.